# How to setup a tabbed activity as a main activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

Can anyone guide me how to make a tabbed activity with 3 tabs as my launcher activity(similar to Whatsapp) for my application.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In your application manifest add this intent filter to your activity :

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And remove this filter from your current launcher activity.